# How to make a custom key modifier?

Tags: autohotkey

Im trying to create a script that will make the Left mouse button press the tilde key (`) while (x) is being held down and return to left clicking once i release the (x) button

Answer (score 1):

with ahk v1.1+ from http://ahkscript.com

you can do it like this

```
#If GetKeyState("x", "P")
    LButton::Send ``{space}
#If
```

Hope it helps